# How to show $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-x^{2 n}}{1-x^{n}} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^{2 n-1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

I've tried many different ways of rearranging the expression $\frac{1-x^{2 n}}{1-x^{n}}=\frac{1}{1-x^{2 n-1}}$ , but I can not seem to prove that the left hand side equals the right hand side.

Am I missing something?

This is part of a larger formula in this paper on proving the Euler partition identity with generating functions. `https://people.clas.ufl.edu/alladik/files/alladipaperpaule60-1.pdf`

Comment: Equality does not hold for e.g. $x\to 1$.

Comment: Also false for all sufficiently large values of $x$.

Comment: Cross multiply and you'll see they aren't remotely the same thing---one side is a polynomial of degree $4n-1$, the other is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: This would tell you that $$
1 + x^n  = \frac{1}{{1 - x^{2n - 1} }}
$$ which is clearly false in general.

Comment: So what you are actually asking is why $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-x^{2 n}}{1-x^{n}} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^{2 n-1}}$

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but I, perhaps wrongly, assumed that the pi notation could be removed.

Comment: @Joe Clinton, do you know what the "pi notation" as you write means?

Comment: I'm guessing you were hoping a term-by-term equality would prove equality of the products. Unfortunately, in this case, you'll have to prove the products are equal by different means. I suggest writing out a few terms of each to see if you notice anything.

Comment: You can write $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^n}=\frac{\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^{2n})}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)}$.  Then $(1-x^{2n})$ in the numerator cancels with the terms $(1-x^k)$ with even $k$ in the denominator.

Comment: @BernardMassé yes, it's the infinite product from n= 1 of the expression. Like sigma sums but for products. I'm guessing my mistake was to assume if $\prod{a} = \prod{b}$ then $a=b$?

Comment: @JoeClinton: $1 \cdot 2 = 2 \cdot 1$ does not imply that $1=2$ :)

Comment: @ipst Ah, yep, that makes alot of sense I see why you can't just get rid of the infinite product thank you so much.

Comment: Some suggestions to improve the question: State your *actual* problem. Don't put it in the title only. Then explain how you tried to solve it, and how that failed.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for suggestions and all your help. In future I'll make sure to do exactly what you've suggested. (I could edit the title and question now, but it would make the comments not make sense)

Comment: One should not invalidate an *answer,* but comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time. One can even flag comments as “outdated”. The comments should not prevent you from improving the question.

Comment: @MartinR I've now changed the question title to the true title and put how I wrongly attempted it into the body of the question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms in the numerator and the terms with even $n $ in the denominator cancel, so that only terms with odd $n $ in the denominator survive. I assume that $|x|<1$ so that the product converges.